# Возврат координат мыши относительно определённого окна после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpushbutton, mousepressevent

Подскажите пожалуйста способ определения координат мыши относительно определённого окна после нажатия на кнопку.

Т.е. нажимаем кнопку, затем идёт определение координат, после отпускания в определённом месте окна **`ЛКМ`** - координаты фиксируются, выводятся и на этом действие кнопки прекращается. 
Больше она координаты определять не должна.

Пытался сделать как-то вот так:

```
import mouse    

...

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_cursorPositionChanged)

def on_cursorPositionChanged(self):
    mouse.on_click(lambda: self.mousePressEvent())

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    print('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()))
```

Но оно работает постоянно и да, код выше не работает.

---

Для примера -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом деле вывод в консоль - для наглядности, а так после получения с ними будут проводиться другие манипуляции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Qt* обнаруживает только щелчок внутри виджета, если вы хотите обнаруживать вне виджетов, тогда вы должны использовать другую библиотеку,
которая использует ресурсы *ОС* для мониторинга событий *ОС*, например **`pynput`**.

```
import sys
from pynput import mouse                                  # pip install pynput
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ButtonReleaseManager(QtCore.QObject):               # !!!
    released = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=self._handle_click)
        self._listener.start()

    def _handle_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if not pressed:
            self.released.emit(x, y)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 400, 100)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton)

    def func_connect(self):
        self.manager = ButtonReleaseManager()                       # !!!
        self.manager.released.connect(self.show_position)           # !!!
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
    
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def show_position(self, x, y):
        screen_coordinate = f"x:{x}, y:{y}"
        self.textEdit.setText(screen_coordinate)
        self.manager.released.disconnect()                          # !!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Мне вот именно внутри виджет нужно координаты определить т.к. это влияет на правильность постановки внутри виджета

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(f'def mousePressEvent(self, event): {event.pos()}')
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton): 
            print(f'def mouseMoveEvent(self, event): {event.pos()}') #

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.parent.flag:
            self._pos = event.pos()
            print(f'def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event): {event.pos()} <----') 
            
            self.parent.label_pos.setText(
                f"<b style='color: #fff'>.</b> x:{self._pos.x()}, y:{self._pos.y()}")
            self.parent.label_pos.move(self._pos.x(), self._pos.y())
            self.parent.label_pos.adjustSize()
            self.parent.flag = False
            

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.flag = False
        
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.setFixedSize(570, 316)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("image1.png"))
        
        self.label_pos = QLabel(self.label)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add', self.label)
        self.pushButton.move(10, 10)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.label)

    def func_connect(self):
        self.flag = True
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне вот именно внутри виджет нужно координаты определить т.к. это влияет на правильность постановки внутри виджета

Comment: Добавил как это примерно будет происходить

Comment: @OverNiko я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: @OverNiko что  не так?

Comment: S. Nick Оу, извините, не было времени зайти и проверить ответ, а можно как-то перестать отслеживать нажатия мыши после выбора точки координат ?

Comment: Пытаюсь сдружить свой код и Ваш, но пока без успешно, у меня уже есть класс Label, mousePressEvent и mouseReleaseEvent уже имеются в нём

Comment: @OverNiko все можно. Примите решение по данному вопросу и задайте новый вопрос, в котором приведите свой код и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Думаю выкладывать все 400+ строк такое себе

Comment: @OverNiko  400+ строк это так себе и не много, но вы можете убрать те места, которые не влияют на суть вашего вопроса. Но пример должен быть воспроизводимым и демонстрировать проблему.

Comment: Создал новую тему

Comment: А как мне из Label вытащить _pos в другой класс ?

Comment: Точнее в MainWindow

Comment: @OverNiko если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Создал новую тему